# How to efficiently turn a particular element (which is a scalar) of each list in a list into a vector?

Tags: r

My current way is

```
coalesce <- function(x){
  if (is.null(x)) NA else x
}

data[,aa:=sapply(JSON, function(x) coalesce(x$a))]
data[,bb:=sapply(JSON, function(x) x$b)]

> JSON <- list(list(a=1, b=1), list(b=2))
> JSON
[[1]]
[[1]]$a
[1] 1

[[1]]$b
[1] 1


[[2]]
[[2]]$b
[1] 2


> sapply(JSON, function(x) coalesce(x$a))
[1]  1 NA
> sapply(JSON, function(x) x$b)
[1] 1 2
```

`JSON` is a list of lists, each list may contain `a` which I would like to grab. If `a` doesn't exist, `NA` is returned. Each list must contain `b`. Both `a` and `b` are always scalars.

My `Rprof` tells me the majority time spent lies in `sapply` and `Fun` and `coalesce`.

I am wondering if there is any way to improve it?

#### Update

Sample data

```
x <- list(a=1, b=1)
y <- list(a=1)
JSON <- rep(list(x,y),300000)

system.time(sapply(JSON, function(x) x$a))
system.time(sapply(JSON, function(x) coalesce(x$b)))
```

Comment: where is your sample data?

Comment: is `a` (or `b`) always just 1 number?

Comment: @eddi yes it is scalar for every list. That's why `sapply` works in my case, otherwise it won't return vector

Comment: you can get some speedup by using `[[` operator instead: `sapply(JSON, function(x) coalesce(x[['a']]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try coalescing after you extract the value and stick to `lapply`, that should speed things up (and if you posted a reasonable benching sample, we could test it):

```
unlist(lapply(lapply(JSON, "[[", "a"), coalesce))
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an error in the way you're using `sapply` - what you want is:

```
sapply(JSON, function(x) coalesce(x)$a)
```

But that's really not optimal, and returns `NULL` when `coalesce` returns `NA` (probably not what you want.

Modify `coalesce`:

```
coalesce <- function(x){
  if (is.null(x$a)) NA else x$a
}
```

And do:

```
data[,b:=sapply(JSON, coalesce)]
```

Comment: I don't get what's the error in my code? I mean, I cannot see any difference between your modified version and my original code, except that you put `$a` inside `coalesce`?

Comment: I put `$a` outside `coalesce` because I think `coalesce` should do what it means - turn `NULL` to a default value i.e. `NA`, not any additional functional.